# How to prove $\int \frac{1}{(x\sin(x))^2}\,dx$ doesnt have an elementary closed form?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, elementary-functions

I know about elementary functions and their integrals, also some elementary function does not have elementary anti-derivative. For example $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ ,
$x^x$ does not have elementary anti-derivatives in spite of being elementary functions.

The given integral  $\int \frac{1}{(x\sin(x))^2}\,dx$ , if I start solving it by putting,

$$\sin^2(x) = (1 - \cos(2x))/2$$

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2(1 - \cos(2x))/2}\,dx$$

$$\int \frac{2}{x^2(1 - \cos(2x))}dx$$

dividing and multiplying by $(1 - \cos(2x))$ , we get

$$2\int \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{x^2(1 - \cos(2x))^2}\,dx$$

replacing numerator $(1 - \cos(2x))$  with  $2 \sin^2(x)$

$$2\int \frac{2 \sin^2(x)}{x^2(1 - \cos(2x))^2}\,dx$$

after rearranging the above equation we get:

$$4\int \frac{ \sin^2(x)}{x^2}\frac{1}{(1 - \cos(2x))^2}\,dx$$

$$4\int \left(\frac{ \sin(x)}{x}\right)^{\!2}\frac{1}{(1 - \cos(2x))^2}\,dx$$

Now as the given integral contains $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ which has no elementary anti-derivative, is this the sufficient condition to say that the given function cannot be integrated?

If this is so, then can we say that any function containing $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ ,
$x^x$ or any such functions cannot have elementary anti-derivative?

**EDIT** : Please also provide a solution for this problem as the result is calculated by @Dr.SonnhardGraubner in comments.

Comment: not integrable in which sense ? That you can't compute by hand ? That is not Riemann integrable over $\mathbb R$ ? Not Lebesgue integrable over $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: No it's not enough, 
$$
\int \frac{\sin x}{x}x\mathrm dx
$$
also contains $\sin x/x$, it can be integrated in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @Surb because the anti-derivative cannot be calculated in terms of elementary fucntions

Comment: you will get this here $${\frac {-2\,i}{ \left(  \left( {{\rm e}^{ix}} \right) ^{2}-1 \right) {
x}^{2}}}-4\,\int \!{\frac {i}{{x}^{3} \left(  \left( {{\rm e}^{ix}}
 \right) ^{2}-1 \right) }}{dx}
$$

Comment: @qbert I got your point but how to prove that this function (given in question) has not elementary anti-derivative ?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Please explain your result, how did you get this

Comment: @sharq I don't know, seems hard

Comment: express the sin-function by the exponential function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that $\int (x\sin(x))^{-2} \mathrm{d}x$ does not have an elementary antiderivative.

However, your reasoning is incorrect.  It is entirely possible for $f(x)$ to not have an antiderivative but $f(x)g(x)$ to have one.  @qbert gave an excellent example with $f(x) = \sin(x)/x$ and $g(x) = x$.  But a somewhat less trivial example would be what occurs when both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are $\sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin^2(x)}$, which is the form of the incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind.

Typically, the method computers use to find the antiderivative or prove the non-existence of an antiderivative is [the Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

For us humans, there are other options for certain functions such as the theorem of Liouville.  Which states that if you have rational functions $f$ and $g$, $g$ nonconstant, the antiderivative

$$\int [f(x)\exp(g(x))] \, \mathrm dx$$

can be expressed in terms of elementary functions if and only if there exists some rational function $h$ such that it is a solution to the differential equation:

$$f = h' + hg$$

This is from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/163/25445), which seems to address your question in somewhat more broad terms.

Somewhat off-topic.  I believe you may have made an error in computation.  I don't see how you suddenly got $(1 - \cos(2x))^4$, shouldn't this be $(1- \cos(2x))^2$?

Comment: Thanks , I have made the corrections.